# Calculating a 3X3 rotational matrix in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and currently I'm taking an intro class with C++ with no programming background aside from HTML.

So my first assignment is to make a program that calculates a 3X3 rotational matrix. Now the problem is, I have no idea how I to start it out. I'm still lost on what a 3X3 rotational matrix is. I understand this should be simple, by testing my abilities of using cin/cout and the use of operators.

I only know how to use cin/cout basically.

The end result should look like this:

[image]

So this is what I'm at so far, hopefully I'm on the right track: Imported iostream, cmath, and iomanip libraries and setup the cout/cin's.

The four inputs, a rotation angle in radians, and an x, y, and z value of a vector to rotate around

So I have theta, ux,yz and uz setup in cout | cin like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){

cout << "Enter Theta:"
cin >> theta;

cout << "Enter ux:"
cin >> ux;

cout << "Enter uy:"
cin >> uy;

cout << "Enter uz:"
cin >> uz;

cout << "OutMatrix:"
cin >> 


}
```

Hopefully once I get this assignment done I'd be able to understand everything a lot better, programming seems really fun if you know the basics. I'm just lost on this assignment though.

Also offtopic, when I use Geany over an SSH it's really laggy. Tried it on my windows computer and linux with the same results. Is there a way I can fix that or is that just due to the nature of using a IDE through SSH?

EDIT: I should have clarified, we haven't gone over arrays yet since this is our first assignment so we're just getting into the basics. It should be calculated with this formula [image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/f/b/a/fbaee547c3c65ad3d48112502363378a.png] so I'm assuming I should put that in the cin part of OutMatrix?

Comment: I highly recommend using a Matrix library or studying how to use 2 dimensional arrays and vectors.  You'll also have to use loops, which I don't think exist in HTML.

Comment: Also studying Linear Algebra, especially transformation matrices would help too.

Comment: What operations do you need to perform on a 3x3 matrix? "Calculating a 3x3 rotational matrix" seems pretty vague.

Comment: Here's some links to get you started. [3x3 Rotation and Identity Matrices](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/3x3-identity-and-rotation-matrices-and-how-they-work.686697/). [Creating Matrices In C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/35642/). Good Luck!

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I've added some more information at the bottom I should have clarified earlier. The four inputs that needs to be entered: a rotation angle in radians, and an x, y, and z value of a vector to rotate around. We're doing the basics at the moment so we haven't gotten to Arrays yet.

Comment: In that case, beware of any help you receive here.  You'd be better off asking a TA or the teacher for advice instead of using anything advanced that you might receive from here.

Comment: How do you implement the matrix without arrays?  I'd really like to know how the instructor wants you to implement matrix multiplication without arrays.

Comment: Would it be something as simple as outputmatrix = formulahere; ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the last `cin >>` is an input statement, but you should *output* the result. That's `cout <<`.

Secondly, since you didn't cover arrays yet, it's easiest to just write out all 9 elements individually. You'll learn more efficient methods later on.

To get everything nicely aligned, `'\t'` is a tab (move to next column) and `'\n'` is a newline.